# Is it possible to feed data from Firebase to GA4? (Nuances of this query in description body)

Tags: firebase, connection, integration, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I'm a CSM for a Mobile App SaaS platform and we use Firebase to track the event based analytics of user engagement ie. specific page views, top actions etc.

I've had requests from mutliple customers now to "integrate" that event based data into their GA4 accounts, ultimately to feed this into Looker Studio to manipulate the data.

The one challenge is that as a SaaS provider, we own the Firebase account and invite the customer to the specific project while they have their own GA4 accounts which adds a layer of complexity.

I've had a play around to see what options for integrations are avaialable (doesn't look like GA4 or Looker Studio are options).

Has anybody had expeirence feeding this data through as at this point, I'm not sure the feed of data would be relevant to GA4.

Not managed to get too far yet, was hoping to get some advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Even before GA4, we've routed our FB data through GA. In fact, it's more like GA is a proper interface with proper APIs to access it.

Theoretically, what you could do is make your GA4 account, connect all your FB data to your GA4, then export it all to BQ, then run a simple ETL to split it by client and give the clients access to their respective BQs.

However, realistically, there's no reason why you'd keep all the data in one FB account. In fact, there's a good reason not to do that. There are limits you can start hitting.

The best course of action would be splitting all the clients' traffic into separate FB accounts and give them the ownership of those. I can't imagine a situation where a SAAS would be entitled to the clients' data, but if that's indeed the case then you probably only need a fraction of the data FB tracks, so you should be able to set up very simplistic custom tracking there to your custom endpoints since as far as I remember, Firebase doesn't allow more than one FB property per its SDK instance.